# How to change colormap in joypy plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, ridgeline-plot

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
  Team  Minute  Type
   148      12     1
   148      22     1
   143      27     1
   148      29     1
   143      32     1
   143      32     1
```

I created a joyplot using the Python library [joypy](https://github.com/sbebo/joypy)

```
fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(df, by="Team", column="Minute", figsize =(10,16), x_range = [0,94], linewidth = 1, colormap=plt.cm.viridis)
```

Which gave me this plot:

[image]

All Good.
However, the colourmap is meaningless now so I am trying to color the plots according to a second dataframe - which is the sum of `Type` for all the teams.

To do that, I created a norm, and a colourmap using these lines:

```
norm = plt.Normalize(group_df["Type"].min(), group_df["Type"].max())
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ar = np.array(group_df["Type"])
Cm = cmap(norm(ar))
sm.set_array([])
```

Here's where the problem arose as I can't figure out how to change the color of the joyplots. I tried a couple of approaches:

1. I tried to pass this `Cm` as the colormap argument. However, that threw up an error - `typeerror 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`
2. I tried to use a for loop over the `axes` and `Cm` -

```
for col, ax in zip(Cm, axes):
    ax.set_facecolor(col)
    #ax.patch.set_facecolor(col) ##Also tried this; didn't change anything
```

How can I get greater control over the colours of the joyplot and change them around? Any help would be appreciated.

### **MCVE**

Sample of the csv file I'm reading in(Actual shape of dataframe is (4453,2)):

```
      Team  Minute
0      148       5
1      148       5
2      148      11
3      148      11
4      148      12
5      148      22
6      143      27
```

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"path")

##getting the sum for every team - total of 20 teams
group_df = df.groupby(["Team"]).size().to_frame("Count").reset_index()
  
df["Minute"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Minute"])

##Trying to create a colormap 
norm = plt.Normalize(group_df["Count"].min(), group_df["Count"].max())
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ar = np.array(group_df["Count"])
Cm = cmap(norm(ar))
sm.set_array([])


fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(df, by="Team", column="Minute", figsize =(10,16), x_range = [0,94], colormap = plt.cm.viridis)
```

I want to color every subplot in the plot by the total count of the team from the `group_df["Count"]` values. Currently, the colormap is just uniform and not according to the total value. The picture above is what's produced.

Comment: You might be successful in providing `joyplot` with a list of colors instead of a colormap. If not, creating this kind of plot might be easier be done manually where you have full control over everything, not only colors.

Comment: Thank you again, that looks like it might work out. How do I create this kind of plot manually? I thought Joypy was the only package available for creating joyplots. I'm still curious though. Why does ax.set_facecolor() not work; is that a bug?

Comment: For example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729039/stacked-density-plots-with-pandas-and-seaborn/54729242#54729242)

Comment: `ax.set_facecolor()` sets the color of the axes, so it wouldn't help. The reason you don't see it have any effect is that the axes is turned off anyways. I can help you more if you provided a running example ([mcve], [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that I can modify.

Comment: I just did that, will this be okay? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: If that returns the axes, how do I get a handle on the individual plots?

Comment: Passing a list of colours didn't work as there is no argument for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

joypy fills the colors of the KDE curves sequentially from a colormap. So in order to have the colors match to a third variable you can supply a colormap which contains the colors in the order you need. This can be done using a `ListedColormap`.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(21)
import pandas as pd
import joypy

df = pd.DataFrame({"Team" : np.random.choice([143,148,159,167], size=200),
                   "Minute" : np.random.randint(0,100, size=200)})

##getting the sum for every team - total of 20 teams
group_df = df.groupby(["Team"]).size().to_frame("Count").reset_index()
print(group_df)



##Trying to create a colormap 
norm = plt.Normalize(group_df["Count"].min(), group_df["Count"].max())
ar = np.array(group_df["Count"])

original_cmap = plt.cm.viridis
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(original_cmap(norm(ar)))
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=original_cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(df, by="Team", column="Minute", x_range = [0,94], colormap = cmap)
fig.colorbar(sm, ax=axes, label="Count")

plt.show()
```

[image]